# add a menu to my application

Tags: android

I'm starting in android. I want to add a menu to my application

How can I do it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should visit the android developer site, looks like u have not tried anything and neither read the android developer site. see that first

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html) offers a listing of the full features of Menu including ways to get started using them in your applications.

Furthermore, the Android Developers site also has [a great guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) covering the various uses/styles/etc of Menus in Android.

I would highly encourage you to look at the documentation at the [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/index.html) site simply because it is well done and gives thorough answers to these types of questions (particularly getting started questions).